# Can I change the PATH variable for a single window?

Tags: windows, batch-file, environment-variables, codeblocks

I'm trying to set up Code::Blocks on a Windows 7 machine without administrator privileges.  I've installed Code::Blocks and MinGW, but I can't edit the user or system PATH variable.

I can open a command line with the required changes to the PATH variable with the following .bat file:

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;c:\mingw\bin
cmd
```

If I try to open Code::Blocks the same way, using the following .bat file:

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;c:\mingw\bin
C:\CodeBlocks\codeblocks.exe
```

Code::Blocks opens, but the PATH variable is unchanged so it can't compile.

Is there any way to change the PATH variable for a single application?  I'd prefer this solution because it can be applicable in other circumstances.

If that's not possible, is there any way to add to the searched PATH in Code::Block's settings?

Comment: your `SET` is local only to the current cmd session, it does not make permanent changes to the environment variable `%PATH%`. You may want to look at `SETX` for that, or make the change directly in the environment variable from the GUI.

Comment: If running codeblocks.exe starts a new instance of the IDE, it will definitely inherit the environment variable changes from the batch script. However, if it shows an already-running instance of the IDE, then obviously it won't inherit the environment from the batch script.

Comment: @Compo, programs get their environment from the parent process, either implicitly or explicitly passed as the `lpEnvironment` parameter of `CreateProcess`. They do not get a fresh environment loaded from the registry. setx.exe and the control panel environment variable editor broadcast a `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` "Environment" message to top-level windows, but generally only Explorer reloads its environment in response to this message.

Comment: @Compo I can't make permanent changes to the environment variable because I don't have administrator privileges.

Comment: @eryksun It seems like the batch file is starting a new instance of the IDE, but it still gives an error because `libgmp-10.dll` is missing.  I think that's happening because `C:\mingw\bin` isn't in the PATH, but I suppose it could be caused by a broken installation of minGW.

Comment: @izoughe, that's what the user environment variable is for! Where it specifically says in the GUI box, `User variables for izoughe`

Comment: If you want to know for sure, you can inspect the `PATH` value of the codeblocks.exe process using [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer). Double click on the process in the list and click on the dialog's "Environment" tab. (Its UI is bad. Drag the column separator until it's wide enough to see the whole value.)

Comment: @Compo I can't access the GUI for the global or the user 'PATH' without administrator privileges.  I will look into 'SETX'.

Comment: @eryksun The 'PATH' does include `C:\mingw\bin`, so it probably is a broken installation of MinGW.

Comment: @izoughe, are you telling me that entering the following command line, `Control sysdm.cpl,,3` does not bring up a window in which to select the `Environment Variables…` button?

Comment: @Compo it does not.  It brings up a prompt for an administrator username and password.

Comment: If your system is locked down from basic things in the GUI, what made you think that it would be wise to install `Code::Blocks` and `MinGW` and expect no issues? Are you locked out of the registry key, `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment` too? so you could create a `PATH` value with your chosen data within that key.

Comment: To diagnose DLL load issues, enable loader snaps: `gflags.exe <name of executable> +sls`. Diagnostics are displayed in a debugger's output window. Use DebugView if you don't want to run a debugger.

Comment: @Compo if I can get this to work, I can stop bringing my own computer in to work every day and save myself a little bit of trouble.  If I can't get it to work, I keep doing exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: The environment variable editor defaults to editing system environment variables, which requires administrator access. Thus the default behavior cannot be used to edit the environment of a standard user. But it can be invoked for just the current user instead. You can do this directly from the start menu (i.e. type "environment"), or from the control panel user accounts applet ("change my environment variables"), or directly from the command line via `rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables`.

Comment: None of which are necessary, if when you told us that "The 'PATH' does include `C:\mingw\bin`", you weren't mistaken!